# UITextView delegate methods not firing

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uitextview

My UITextView delegate methods aren't firing.

```
UILabel *fieldLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 290, 20)];
fieldLabel.text = nodeproperty.name;
[rowsInSectionLabels addObject:fieldLabel];
UITextView *textViewStatus = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 25, 290, 30)];
[textViewStatus setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

// For the border and rounded corners
[[textViewStatus layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
[[textViewStatus layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
[[textViewStatus layer] setBorderWidth:1];
[[textViewStatus layer] setCornerRadius:5];
[textViewStatus setClipsToBounds: YES];
textViewStatus.delegate = self;
[textViewStatus setEditable:YES];
```

My Interface

```
@interface WorkflowViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, PickerRowSelected>
```

I added a breakpoint here and nothing...

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    MultilineTextViewController *multiLineText = [[MultilineTextViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:multiLineText animated:YES];
}
```

Any ideas?

All my other delegate methods work perfectly

Comment: Does the keyboard show up? Do you have breakpoints enabled? Did you implement `- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` returning `YES`? This is not neccessery but you could try if it gets fired.

Comment: The keyboard does show up and I can type in the UITextView, even that delegate method does not get fired, yes breakpoints are enabled, I have other breakpoints also in that view that I catch

Comment: How is this textView added to the view of the WorkflowViewController? It seems you do it programatically. Do you hold any reference to it (property, iVar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was making a silly mistake with enums and adding the UITextView to the View, I have a if statement that adds either a textview or textfield and the if adding the textview didn't work as expected, all works now